# &nbsp; HTML markup renders not as expected

Tags: html, asp.net

Two ASP.NET Web form pages:

**Page1:**

Type: Normal asp.net page, no containers or database binding controls

Rendered as: `Content Content`

Source (as shown in browser tool): `<p>Content&nbsp;Content</p>`

(Life is happy)

**Page2:**

Type: Database content, using DetailsView Control

Rendered as: `Content&nbsp;Content`

Source (as shown in browser tool): `<p>Content&nbsp;Content</p>`

I'm gonna be mad why does that happen! I want the `&nbsp;` to be a blank space!

Is that DetailsView charm or what!!

Appendix:
**Page2 markup**

```
    <ItemTemplate>
    <%--Title--%>
    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("title") %>'></asp:Label>

    <br />

    <%--Date--%>
    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("date") %>'></asp:Label>

    <br />

    <%--Content--%>
    <p>
        <asp:Literal ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("content") %>' />
    </p>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Note that I tried the `asp:Label` and `asp:Literal`

Comment: What is the string as stored in the database? Check that `&nbsp;` has not been stored as `&amp;nbsp;`

Comment: @JonP actually that's true, but in the browser source, both of them represented as &nbsp; can you give me more details about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you would need two-way databinding on a label, so I would probably go back to using something like the following:

```
<%--Content--%>
    <p>
        <asp:Literal ID="lblContent" runat="server" Text='<%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)Eval("content")) %>' />
   </p>
```

Comment: The `Bind()` is the DetailsView Default, but I think you mean `HtmlDecode()`, that worked, but it's not safe I think

Comment: True, generally you want to `HtmlEncode()` any user-derived input before you display the data in order to be safe. I would imagine that the data might have been encoded before storing in the database as @Jon P mentioned in a comment above. Worth checking. If that's the case, you may want to look into sanitizing your data before storing instead of encoding. The general practice is to store whatever the user gives you, but encode it before displaying. Some people disagree, though.